# How to unhide the cursor without changing the application

Tags: windows, flash, touchscreen

I need to do a pre-purchase evaluation of a Flash application that is intended for a touch screen.

Since I still don't have the touchscreen now, I need to run the application on my desktop computer and the application is unusable without a visible cursor.

I am using Windows.

Is there a way to unhide the cursor without asking the developers to change the application?

Answer (score 0):

I've previously used remote access software (such as Windows Remote Desktop or TeamViewer) for this purpose. Another option is a virtual machine - in both cases you'll be able to see the cursor on the local/host machine.

If you happen to be on a Windows 8 machine, you might give a try to the Windows Simulator (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/09/29/first-look-at-windows-simulator.aspx, available for free with Visual Studio Express) that additionally simulates multitouch gestures such as pinch/rotate with only a mouse.

A few other ideas:

1) You can try using the "Show location of pointer when I press the CTRL key" mouse visibility property (Control Panel - Hardware and Sound - Devices and Printers - Mouse - Pointer options). Although not entirely convenient, it might help you if the application doesn't require quick response times.

2) If the application is distributed as a .swf file and the right button hasn't been disabled, sometimes right-clicking (anywhere in the application) to bring up the context menu will cause the cursor to show up and remain visible.